# Change a requiered value from input with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the required value from a input base on a check box selection, here is what I have so far....   thanks

```
<input type="checkbox" id="no_land_line" name="no_land_line" value="”/> // if no land line check here


    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#no_land_line').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
        {
          $('#no_land_line_div').fadeOut('slow');
          document.getElementById("land_line").setAttribute("required", true);
          document.getElementById("cellphone").setAttribute("required", false);

        }
        else {
         document.getElementById("land_line").setAttribute("required", false);
         document.getElementById("cellphone").setAttribute("required", true);
         $('#no_land_line_div').fadeIn('slow');

                }
    });
});
</script>


<input type="text" name="land_line" id="land_line" required="true"/>  // landline number
<input type="tel" name="cellphone" id="cellphone" required="false"/> // cellphone number

<div id="no_land_line_div”>some text</div>
```

UPDATE WITH A WORKING CODE

Comment: I went ahead and created a jsfiddle for this. Hope it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/o75d3Lso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your use of javascript:

```
document.getElementById("land_line").setAttribute("required", false);
document.getElementById("cellphone").setAttribute("required", true);
```

Comment: thank you it work this way,, I update the code on this question to the working code

Comment: No problem :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

required is not a javascript property.

Change

```
getElementById("land_line").required = false,
getElementById("cellphone").required = true;
```

to

```
$("#land_line").attr("required",false);
    $("#cellphone").attr("required",true);
```

Here's the entire script code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#no_land_line').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
        {
          $('#no_land_line_div').fadeOut('slow'),
          $("#land_line").attr("required",false);
          $("#cellphone").attr("required",true);
        }
        else {
          $('#no_land_line_div').fadeIn('slow'),
           $("#land_line").attr("required",true);
          $("#cellphone").attr("required",false);
                }
    });
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/23rdtjwq/4/

Comment: Thank you Dinomyte, when I check the checkbox it removes the required from the #land_line but is no adding required  to  #cellphone

Comment: I've added a fiddle link for reference. check that.